# Tmux configuration to stop scrolling

Tags: scroll, terminal, command, tmux

Anyone familiar with how to disable scrolling through command history so that the mouse scroll can only be used for navigating up and down the page instead of the specific commands?

Comment: you need to enter `copy-mode` first. by default, this is bound to `prefix-[`. `q`, `Esc`, or `C-c` will let you exit `copy-mode`

Comment: Is it possible to permanently disable scrolling through command history? I wish to type commands and scroll through outputs and it would be easier to do that without switching modes